# Chrome font-display CSS property

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I've been testing out `font-display` recently, however my Chrome browser (Chrome 65) at both work (Centos 7) and home (Windows 10) doesn't seem to recognize it as a valid property. Looking in DevTools, the property has the yellow exclamation mark next to it, saying "Unknown Property Name".

It was my understanding that `font-display` has been supported in Chrome since version 63.

For reference, I'm trying to set the value of `font-display` to `swap`.

Anyone have any ideas why I'm not seeing it work?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the CSS you're using.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`font-display` is  a property only on `@font-face` rules, not standard elements. [See @font-face examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Comment: To be more precise, it's not a property at all, it's a @font-face descriptor. CSS calls these descriptors for a reason. People calling them "properties" is why questions like this get asked.

Comment: Correct, although I wouldn't go as far as saying it's why questions like these get asked. Personally I find the different terminology needless, but to each their own... Either way, upvoting as "descriptor" is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up my misunderstanding. Makes much more sense that it's on the `@font-face` rule

Answer (score 8):

The `font-display` descriptor should be used with the `@font-face` rule as in the following example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Arvo';
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Arvo'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/arvo/v9/rC7kKhY-eUDY-ucISTIf5PesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Documentation on this is [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/font-display)

Comment: Thank you for your response